# Redmine project data for all projects

Tags: redmine

I am working on creating a dashboard which would access Redmine project data. This dashboard will be a consolidation of project data (delivery date, manager, start date, total issues, open issues, closed issues, bug count etc.) for all projects in the Redmine database.

Any ideas on how to do this? An SQL query to achieve this would be a good start. I have Redmine setup on my local system and can access the Redmine database.

I plan on creating an HTML5 .Net based web application. Once I figure out the queries to be used, I would write an IIS (or REST) service to fetch the desired data from the Redmine production database.

Any help/pointers would be deeply appreciated.

Regards,
Pranjal

Answer (score 3):

You have basically three options:

1. use the REST API
2. develop a redmine plug-in
3. do some custom SQL stuff

#### REST API

The best you could do is to use the [redmine REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api). Using it, you can fetch the data directly from redmine without any SQL queries or manipulating the server. It should even work when the redmine server is updated.

#### Redmine Plug-in

The next best thing is probably to develop a [redmine plug-in](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Developer_Guide). Your plug-in can access redmine classes (`Project`, `User`, etc.). For example, you could do something like `Projects.all.map {|p| [p.id, p.identifier]}` to get the id and identifier of all projects in an array. This approach is way more powerful than using the REST API, but you have to modify the redmine server (install and maintain your plug-in). A plug-in is probably more fragile when redmine changes internal structures, than the REST API.

#### Custom SQL stuff

I do not recommend developing custom SQL solutions, but it is an option. Such a solution is harder to develop, more fragile, harder to set up, but might offer better performance.
You can see the the redmine database structure listed in `db/schema.rb`. Having the right schema, you could develop your custom SQL queries and return them to your dashboard.

#### Think about security

Apart from the usual security stuff (which you should consider too :)), remember that redmine has a rich permission system. Consider which object you make (publicly) available. This is most important for the last two options. When using the plug-in approach, you should have a look at [the `User#allowed_to` method](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L509).

With the little information I have about your requirements, I have the feeling that **you should go for the REST API**.

Comment: I always wanted to go the SQL way since that is what I am most comfortable with.
However, Redmine REST API, looks like the way forward.
Now, I have to find out for myself if an API that solves my problem already exists. Are you aware of such API's and a repository to find them in? If not, can you tell me how to create one? (my project requirements are listed in the original post above)
Also, do you have any idea on how to work on Redmine REST API on .Net? Any pointers here shall be extremely helpful.

Regards,Pranjal